# passing another variable into rails3 mail receive method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I have a mail_receiver that pulls my email in via pop and then passes that message to my DropBoxMailer like this :

```
DropBoxMailer.receive(email.pop)
```

I need to pass a variable through to the DropBoxMailer class so need to do something like this

```
DropBoxMailer.receive(email.pop, another_var)
```

Does anyone know how to do this properly ?

as receive only expects 1 not 2 params ?

thanks
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
class DropBoxMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  # redefine ActionMailer.receive with an additional parameter
  def self.receive(raw_mail, email_account, another_var)
    ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("receive.action_mailer") do |payload|
      mail = Mail.new(raw_mail)
      set_payload_for_mail(payload, mail)
      new.receive(mail, another_var)
    end
  end

  def receive(mail, another_var)
    ..
  end
end
```

See [example](https://github.com/huerlisi/mailyt/blob/master/app/mailers/basic.rb)